# error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" on new site

Tags: wordpress, email, gmail-api

I am setting up a new WordPress site. I am not a developer. I am trying to use a Google Apps account with the **gmail** API enabled, and Postman **SMTP** to connect my site to **gmail**. Within minutes of setting up the API connection I am getting this error in Postman's email logs: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '

> { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Token has been
>   expired 
>       or revoked." }'

I have even generated a new API secret and put it into the Postman settings. I've enabled and disabled BlueHost's free WordPress SSL. I cannot get my site to send out any sort of email (contact form submissions, order confirmations, etc.). I've contacted BlueHost's tech support and they say it's not them.

Also posted this question on the Postman support thread here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/google-api-11/

Suggestions?

```
POSTMAN DIAGNOSTIC TEST OUTPUT
OS: Linux box5059.bluehost.com 3.12.74-20170619.148.ELK6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon 
Jun 19 19:48:05 CDT 2017 x86_64
PHP: Linux 7.0.12 C
PHP Dependencies: iconv=Yes, spl_autoload=Yes, openssl=Yes, sockets=Yes, 
allow_url_fopen=Yes, mcrypt=Yes, zlib_encode=Yes
WordPress: 4.8.1 en_US UTF-8
WordPress Theme: FocusBlog
WordPress Plugins: Gravity Forms, Akismet Anti-Spam, iThemes Security, 
Facebook for WooCommerce, Imagify, Members, Postman SMTP, Thrive Apprentice, 
Thrive Clever Widgets, Thrive Headline Optimizer, Thrive Leads, Thrive Quiz 
Builder, Thrive Ultimatum, Thrive Visual Editor, UpdraftPlus - 
Backup/Restore, WooCommerce AvaTax, WooCommerce Customer History, 
WooCommerce Amazon Pay Gateway, WooCommerce Stripe Gateway, WooCommerce 
Google Analytics Pro, WooCommerce - Gravity Forms Product Add-Ons, 
WooCommerce, Yoast SEO, WP Rocket
WordPress wp_mail Filter(s): wp_staticize_emoji_for_email
Postman: 1.7.2
Postman Sender Domain (Envelope|Message): OurCityCares.org | 
OurCityCares.org
Postman Prevent Message Sender Override (Email|Name): No | No
Postman Active Transport: Gmail API (https:oauth2://www.googleapis.com:443)
Postman Active Transport Status (Ready|Connected): Yes | Yes
Postman Deliveries (Success|Fail): 0 | 19

POSTMAN CONNECTIVITY TEST OUTPUT
Transport   Socket  Status* Service Available   Server ID   Authentication
None    Login   Plain   CRAM-MD5    OAuth 2.0
SMTP    www.googleapis.com:25   Closed  No  -   -   -   -   -   -
SMTP    www.googleapis.com:465  Closed  No  -   -   -   -   -   -
SMTP    www.googleapis.com:587  Closed  No  -   -   -   -   -   -
Gmail API   www.googleapis.com:443  Open     HTTPS    googleapis.com  n/a
Mandrill API    mandrillapp.com:443 Open     HTTPS    mandrillapp.com n/a
SendGrid API    api.sendgrid.com:443    Open     HTTPS    sendgrid.com    
n/a
* According to portquiz.net

Summary:

✅  Port 443 can be used with the Gmail API.
✅  Port 443 can be used with the SendGrid API.
✅  Port 443 can be used with the Mandrill API.
❌ No outbound route between this site and the Internet on Port 25.
❌ No outbound route between this site and the Internet on Port 587.
❌ No outbound route between this site and the Internet on Port 465.
A test with "No" Service Available indicates one or more of these issues:

Your web host has placed a firewall between this site and the Internet
The SMTP hostname is wrong or the mail server does not provide service on 
this port
Your PHP configuration is preventing outbound connections
Your WordPress configuration is preventing outbound connections
If the issues above can not be resolved, your last option is to configure 
Postman to use an email account managed by your web host with an SMTP server 
managed by your web host.
```

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/token-has-been-expired-or-revoked/) to do a [fresh authorization](https://wphowto.net/gmail-smtp-plugin-for-wordpress-1341). There is an intermittent issue that seems to occur on some servers. When you get this error, it means that the plugin is not being able to refresh the OAuth2 token using the secret access key. It is required by the App that you created in your account to access the Gmail API. Usually, the issue goes away when you delete the existing secret access key from the database and do a fresh authorization.

Comment: I have done that and the issue persists.